# Where is BLAS and LAPACK installed - the directory?

Tags: directory, software-sources, paths

I am trying find which directory path BLAS and LAPACK are installed on.

I tried:

```
$ type libblas-dev
bash: type: libblas-dev: not found
```

Then:

```
$ apt-cache policy libblas-dev
libblas-dev:
  Installed: 3.6.0-2ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.6.0-2ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 3.6.0-2ubuntu2 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

But the last code doesn't show where it is installed. Can anyone help with this?

The same is the case with LAPACK:

```
$ type liblapack3
bash: type: liblapack3: not found
```

and

```
$ apt-cache policy liblapack3
liblapack3:
  Installed: 3.6.0-2ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.6.0-2ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 3.6.0-2ubuntu2 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The command:

```
$ dpkg -L liblapack3
```

gives:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/lapack
/usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/liblapack3
/usr/share/doc/liblapack3/copyright
/usr/share/doc/liblapack3/testing_results.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/liblapack3/README.gz
/usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3
/usr/share/doc/liblapack3/changelog.Debian.gz
```

But how do I know where the executable file is ? i.e. the install directory.

Comment: It's a library... there's no "executable file" AFAIK. Is your real question something like "How do I get xxx installer to find BLAS/LAPACK"?

Comment: Yes, I want cmake, for installing `dealii` graphics package, to include particlualy LAPACK, and therefore to find LAPACK by adding its path.

Comment: Well, as you can see from the `dpkg -L` outputs, Linux doesn't install software to a single directory: instead, it installs files based on their function, according to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). Typically, `cmake` should be able to locate the relevant header files and libraries  based on the `FindBLAS.cmake` and `FindLAPACK.cmake` files that are provided by the `cmake-data` package.